# Using Conditionals in magento email templates

Tags: magento

I am trying to use a conditional in a magento email template.
Specifically the contact us email template.

I have tried the following:

```
{{if var data.name}}
Name: {{var data.name}}
{{/if}}
```

Where "Name: xxx" will only be printed if there is content in the 'name' form field.
For some reason the content inside the if statement never gets printed even when I test the form with content in the name field.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
{{if customer.getName()}} 
 Name: {{var customer.name}}
{{/if}}
```

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/English/Mage_Adminhtml/system_email_template/index/

Comment: Nope..this doesn't work. I think that applies to logged in customers, although I can be wrong about that.